# How does an array appear to hold a pointer value and an element value at the same location in memory?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory, implicit-conversion

If I have an int array **intArr[4]** and get the address it’s pointing to like so
`printf("%p\n", intArr,);`

Then get the address of the array
`printf(“%p\n”, &intArr);`

Both statements return the same address

**0xffffcc14**

**0xffffcc14**

Then when it is de-referenced either through **intArr[0]** or ***intArr** it gives an integer value.

So I was wondering what is happening to make it seem as though an array is holding two things at the same time in the same memory location: a pointer value to itself and an element value?

Comment: It doesn't. Array is decaying to a pointer when passed to `printf`, so the value of the address of the *first element* is printed. When `&intArr` is printed - it is the address of the array itself, which is the same as the one of the first element for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array you declared

```
intArr[4];
```

in fact is a named extent of memory. So the address of the array and the address of its first element is the address of the extent of memory occupied by the array.

The only difference between the expressions `&intArr` and `intArr` used in the calls of `printf` is their types. The first expression has the pointer type `int ( * )[4]` and the second expression has the pointer type `int *` but the values produced by the expressions are equal each other.

In this call

```
printf("%p\n", intArr,);
```

the array designator is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.

Arrays used in expressions with rare exceptions as for example using them in the `sizeof` operator are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

For example if you will write

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( intArr ) );
```

you will get the size of the array.

On the other hand, if you will write

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( intArr + 0 ) );
```

you will get the size of a pointer because in this expression `intArr + 0` the array designator is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.

As for these expressions `intArr[0]` and `*intArr` then the first expression is evaluated like `*( intArr + 0 )` that is the same as `*intArr`.

Comment: Thanks I guess what I'm trying to ask then is where is the pointer address stored that the array uses when it decays to a pointer? since **intArr[0]** holds an int value, not the pointer value. I hope that seems different than what I just asked.

Comment: @user17917376 The array address is stored nowhere. The compiler tracks addresses of all variables and the linker resolves them.